# subspace of c^3 of a group above complex and real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra

$A = \{(1,2+i, i), (1,3+i, 3-i), (i, 3i, 4+i)\}$

Find the dimension of $Sp_cA$ when A is above the complex numbers, and $Sp_rA$ when A is above the real numbers.

I thought that you could use row reduction since it's above the real numbers you can't do any row reduction and you get that $dim Sp_rA= 3$. and since $Sp_cA$ is above the complex you can do row reduction and get that $dim Sp_cA = 2$, does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $$a(1,2+i, i)+b(1,3+i, 3-i)+c(i, 3i, 4+i)=(0,0,0)$$ (in one case you'll have $a,b,c$ real, in other complex, but now it doesn't matter)

then you have a system of equations:
$$a+b+ci=0$$
$$a(2+i)+b(3+i)+3ci=0$$
$$ai+b(3-i)+c(4+i)=0$$
Multiply the third one by $-1$ and add to second one, then apply the first equation. You'll get $c=0$, what makes the rest of computations quite easy.

Comment: But it does matter whether $a,b,c$ are real or complex ?